# CodeIgniter - MySQL join when there are no rows in secound table

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have this query in model:

> ```
>   public function Games() {
>     $q = $this->db->select('games.id, games.title, games.slug, games.dev_id, games.dev, games.plat_id, games.plat');
>     $q = $this->db->from('games');
>     $q = $this->db->join('rates', 'games.id = rates.game_id');
>     $q = $this->db->select_avg('rates.rate');
>     $q = $this->db->get();
> ```

```
    return $q->result();
}
```

My goal is listing everything from `games`, additionally getting average `rate` from `rates` when available. Now it only shows those rows which are in both tables. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this instruction

```
$this->db->select('games.id, games.title, games.slug, games.dev_id, games.dev, games.plat_id, games.plat');
$this->db->select_avg('rates.rate');
$this->db->from('games');
$this->db->join('rates', 'games.id = rates.game_id','left');
$this->db->group_by('rates.game_id');
$q = $this->db->get();
```

Left join will bring multiple results. using avg and group by will restrict to fetch only one row against each record.

Comment: I tried using `left`, `outer left` etc, but without any results; ( Also, `left` causes `id` to shift from `games` to `rates`, which I don't want to.

Comment: for average rates use $this->db->select_avg('rates.rate') and give alias to game.id as GameId to prevent collision

Comment: and why are you assigning every instruction in $q. The last thing to be used is group by rates.game_id and all will be done

Comment: Yes, grouping helped (which, for some reason, isn't required at all). Thanks! (also, please edit your answer so I can vote it up;))